# IFTTT ASUS Trigger, Device Connected dropdown list shows only 1 device and duplicated in the entire list

Tags: triggers, automation, router, ifttt, asus

I have linked my IFTTT service ASUS successfully to my ASUS RT-AC88U which is on AIMESH mode with a RT-AC66U as a node.

However when I want to create a trigger using the ASUS IFTTT when a specific devices connects to my router, it only shows a single devices instead of all the available devices that are currently connected to the router. (before I reset the router it was way worst as it didn't even show a single connected device)

I turned off the AIMESH node too but still same result.

I have tried restoring the router to factory settings, but to no avail.

Anyone has any idea how to resolve this?

by the way, If I choose that only devices displayed in the drop down list, the IFTTT works and sends me a notification.

[Screenshot of the drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRIwK.png)